# SQL to join two queries and sum like records

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, db2

I am writing a web form page using asp.net. I have two different tables. Both of the tables have the same columns, just different data. For example:

```
Table 1: col1,  col2,  col3
         123   $12.54   Tom
          34   $7.00    Jan

Table 2: col1,  col2,  col3
         123   $125.00  Tom
         56    $12.00   Joe
```

I am trying to write an sql statement that will combine the two tables and if Col1 in table 1 is the same as col1 in table 2, I want to add the values for column 2 together. For example:

```
Col1     col2     col3
123      $137.54    Tom
34       $7.00      Jan
56       $12.00     Joe
```

Here are the sql queries:

Table1:

```
SELECT ABAN8 as Number, SUM(SDAEXP * .01) as SaleAmount, A5POPN as Rep 
FROM KAIPRDDTA.F0101, KAIPRDDTA.F4211, KAIPRDDTA.F0301 
WHERE A5AN8 = ABAN8 
 AND ABAN8 = SDAN8 
 AND SDKCOO = '00001' 
 AND SDDCTO not like '%2' 
 AND A5DAOJ >= '118069' 
 AND A5DAOJ <= '118099' 
 GROUP BY ABALPH, A5POPN, ABAN8, A5UPMT, A5CMC1
```

Table2:

```
SELECT ABAN8 as Number, SUM(SDAEXP * .01) as SaleAmount, A5POPN as Rep 
FROM KAIPRDDTA.F0101, KAIPRDDTA.F42119, KAIPRDDTA.F0301 
WHERE A5AN8 = ABAN8 
 AND ABAN8 = SDAN8 
 AND SDKCOO = '00001' 
 AND SDDCTO not like '%2' 
 AND A5DAOJ >= '118069' 
 AND A5DAOJ <= '118099' 
 GROUP BY ABALPH, A5POPN, ABAN8, A5UPMT, A5CMC1
```

I know the join syntax is out of date, but that's how this company uses it. Let me know if you need any more information and thanks in advance for your responses!

Comment: your data sample and your code seems not related ..

Comment: (1) You mention two tables, but your query has three.  (2) Tag with the database you are using.  (3) Get a job at a company that uses databases correctly.

Comment: I second Gordon's 3rd section. implicit joins is not only out of date, it has been out of date for over 25 years(!).

Comment: Also, what's the deal with the column names? Is the company you work for stuck in 1985, when everything was shorten to the bare minimum because memory was so expensive? That's the kind of spirit that lead to the mass hysteria about the y2k bug... You really, really should either find a better company to work for.

Comment: Why don't you try helping instead of worrying about something that neither of us have control over, Zohar

Comment: @kodym I'm actually in the middle of writing an answer to your question. Please do not take my comments as offensive, (your boss is free to do that, however), It's just out of curiosity and a little bit of steam blowing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's basically fairly easy with coalesce and a full outer join, though I don't know if db2 supports implicit full outer joins.

I'm going to address the sample data you posted, not the queries, because I like to be able to read what I'm writing, and because I feel it's going to be much clearer for everyone who is going to read this - so here goes:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.col1, t2.col1) As col1, 
       COALESCE(t1.col2, 0) +  COALESCE(t2.col2, 0) As col2, 
       COALESCE(t1.col3, t2.col3) As col3
FROM table1 as t1
FULL JOIN table12 as t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col1
```

From what I understand, [DB2 supports implicit left joins and implicit right joins](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052878.html). I couldn't find anything about full join but I suppose it should work like this:

```
FROM table1 as t1, table2 as t2
WHERE t1.col1(+) = t2.col1(+)
```

Comment: I was using COALESCE but didn't think to split up the sales and add them together. This worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :-) Sorry again if my comments on the question seemed offensive to you, that was not my intent.

Comment: The documentation you referenced indicates that the explicit outer join syntax is preferred, and you should only use the outer join syntax when you have to when querying from another RDBMS.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy I'm all for explicit joins everywhere. The OP is working in a company that enforce implicit joins. You can read about it in the comments to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Out of 5 columns in "group by" only 2 columns were selected. It is possible that you might get more than one record for given number and rep. Check whether "UNION ALL" meets your requirement.

```
Select number, sum(SaleAmount) , Rep
from
( SELECT ABAN8 as Number, (SDAEXP * .01) as SaleAmount, A5POPN as Rep 
FROM KAIPRDDTA.F0101, KAIPRDDTA.F4211, KAIPRDDTA.F0301 
WHERE A5AN8 = ABAN8 
 AND ABAN8 = SDAN8 
 AND SDKCOO = '00001' 
 AND SDDCTO not like '%2' 
 AND A5DAOJ >= '118069' 
 AND A5DAOJ <= '118099' 
union all
SELECT ABAN8 as Number,  (SDAEXP * .01) as SaleAmount, A5POPN as Rep 
FROM KAIPRDDTA.F0101, KAIPRDDTA.F42119, KAIPRDDTA.F0301 
WHERE A5AN8 = ABAN8 
 AND ABAN8 = SDAN8 
 AND SDKCOO = '00001' 
 AND SDDCTO not like '%2' 
 AND A5DAOJ >= '118069' 
 AND A5DAOJ <= '118099' 
) a 
group by number , rep
```